# OpenCvSharp VideoWriter writes an empty video

Tags: c#, .net, opencv

I am trying to read a vide file, resize the frames and write them to an output file:

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenCvSharp;
using OpenCvSharp.Extensions;

namespace VideoProcessing
{
    public class Player
    {
        private VideoCapture capture;
        private VideoWriter writer;

        private Mat matInternal;
        public Bitmap bmInternal;

        private bool bIsPlaying = false;
        public Timer MyTimer    = new Timer();

        const string outname = "output.avi";
        OpenCvSharp.Size dsize = new OpenCvSharp.Size(640, 480);   

        public void InitPlayer(string videoName)
        {
            capture = new VideoCapture(videoName);
            writer  = new VideoWriter(outname, FourCC.MJPG, capture.Fps, dsize);

            matInternal = Mat.Zeros(dsize, MatType.CV_8UC3);
            bmInternal = matInternal.ToBitmap();

            var delay = 1000 / (int)capture.Fps;

            MyTimer.Interval = delay;
            MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(mk_onTick());
            MyTimer.Start();
        }

        private Action<object, EventArgs>
        mk_onTick()
        {
            return (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                capture.Read(matInternal);
                if (matInternal.Empty())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Empty frame!");
                }
                else
                {
                    matInternal.Resize(dsize);
                    bmInternal = matInternal.ToBitmap();
                    writer.Write(matInternal);
                }
            };
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            capture.Dispose();
            writer.Dispose();
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is executed in my main function as follows:

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using OpenCvSharp;
using OpenCvSharp.Extensions;

namespace VideoProcessing
{
    internal class Program
    {

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var videoName = "input.mp4";

            var pl = new Player();

            pl.InitPlayer(videoName);

            // Some other code that executes in the meantime

            pl.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

The writer can get disposed before the video finishes, which is fine because this will later be adapted for live camera video streams. However, the VideoWriter here produces an apparently empty, 0 second long video file. The codec setting does not produce any errors, and the video is only at 24 FPS so it should not be running into any speed issues. What could be causing this?

Comment: if it can't find `opencv_videoio_ffmpeg455_64.dll` (or whatever opencv version you're using) at runtime it will write only the 'container header' , but no images. make sure , that dll is on the PATH

Comment: I have added the dll to the path and am still running into the same issue

Comment: check frame sizes. are they the same size you promised to VideoWriter? are they the right data type and channel count? don't just say yes. find it out, add it to the post. -- .avi and MJPG should require no ffmpeg, because avi and mjpeg are built into opencv. -- does `matInternal.Resize` operate in-place or does it return a new matrix?

Comment: I pass the same `Size` to both the writer and the resize method, so that wasn't the issue. However, it turns out `Resize` is indeed not in-place, and I needed to use a different method entirely. Thank you, I will write an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to delay your main thread.
By adding Thread.Sleep(2000) for instance.

I try your code with camera and it works well.